# Java - order of execution after wait

Tags: java, concurrency, wait, notify

all. I have a question for Java wait-notify mechanism. The answer is is there a guaranty that the threads will be executed in this order - from last to the first etc. the result always will be 100, 99, ... , 1 ? This is the snippet of code:

public class Main {

```
static int counter = 0;
static Object o = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (o) {
                try {
                    int c = ++counter;
                    o.wait();
                    System.out.println("" + c);
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    synchronized (o) {
        new Thread(()-> {
            synchronized(o){
                System.out.println("LAsttttttttttttttttt");
            }
        }).start();


        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        o.notifyAll();
    }

}
```

}

I run it 10 times and the result is always the same. I coudn't find anything about this in internet. And one more question - when we have 100 threads waiting, when we notifyAll, is there a guaranty that first one of waiting threads will be executed, after then a second one and after all 100 waiting threads are executed, other waiting methods(which were in synchronized block, but don't have wait() in their body), will be executed after that (after all 100 threads that were waiting are executed). Or notifyAll only guaranty that all waiting threads will start fighting with every method which is synchronized by this object? I thing that this is the answer :
"The awakened threads will not be able to proceed until the current
     * thread relinquishes the lock on this object. The awakened threads
     * will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might
     * be actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example,
     * the awakened threads enjoy no reliable privilege or disadvantage in
     * being the next thread to lock this object."

But I want to be sure that I understand what's going on when we have wait-notify.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No . .there is no guarantee that a set of awoken threads will be executed in any particular order.  (This may happen in order because of a particular implementation of JVM or the speed of the computer the program is run on, or many other load based variables.  However, there is no language guarantee.)

Comment: +1. If you want such a guarantee, use a fair lock: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock%28boolean%29

Answer (score 2):

Java's synchronized code block makes no guarantee about the sequence in which threads waiting to enter the synchronized block are allowed to enter, and `notifyAll()` doesn't present itself as a special case.

As you have seen in [`notifyAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29) javadoc (emphasis mine):

> The awakened threads will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object. **The awakened threads will compete in the usual manner** with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the awakened threads enjoy no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being the next thread to lock this object.