# how the notify() wake up thread in order or at random

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, thread-safety, notify

I know `notify` will wake up the thread which is in wait set at random. But look at the following code

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object co = new Object();
        System.out.println(co);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            MyThread t = new MyThread("Thread" + i, co);
            t.start();
        }

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            System.out.println("-----Main Thread notify-----");

                synchronized (co) {
                    co.notify();
                }

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            System.out.println("Main Thread is end.");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class MyThread extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private Object co;

        public MyThread(String name, Object o) {
            this.name = name;
            this.co = o;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (co) {
                    System.out.println(name + " is waiting.");
                    co.wait();
                    System.out.println(name + " has been notified.");
                    co.notify();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but the threads wake up in order as the thread called `wait()`. It means someone  call `wait()` first, it wakes up first; someone call `wait()` second, it weak up second...

I think it is the error from my code results in this, but I don't know where is the problem.

For convenience to show it, I change the iteration from 20 times, but when it is 1000 times, the result is the same.

```
code.thread.ThreadTest
java.lang.Object@45ee12a7
Thread0 is waiting.
Thread1 is waiting.
Thread2 is waiting.
Thread3 is waiting.
Thread4 is waiting.
Thread5 is waiting.
Thread6 is waiting.
Thread7 is waiting.
Thread9 is waiting.
Thread10 is waiting.
Thread11 is waiting.
Thread8 is waiting.
Thread12 is waiting.
Thread13 is waiting.
Thread14 is waiting.
Thread15 is waiting.
Thread16 is waiting.
Thread17 is waiting.
Thread18 is waiting.
Thread19 is waiting.
-----Main Thread notify-----
Thread0 has been notified.
Thread1 has been notified.
Thread2 has been notified.
Thread3 has been notified.
Thread4 has been notified.
Thread5 has been notified.
Thread6 has been notified.
Thread7 has been notified.
Thread9 has been notified.
Thread10 has been notified.
Thread11 has been notified.
Thread8 has been notified.
Thread12 has been notified.
Thread13 has been notified.
Thread14 has been notified.
Thread15 has been notified.
Thread16 has been notified.
Thread17 has been notified.
Thread18 has been notified.
Thread19 has been notified.
Main Thread is end.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: No reproducable, when the number goes to `1000`, the order is not consistent.

Comment: @JohnSnowDoesNotKnowNothing I have changed it to 1000,the result is the same

Comment: @JohnSnowDoesNotKnowNothing I have changed it to 1000，the result is the same

Comment: On my computer, it's not the same... Maybe you can increase it to 10000

Comment: @JohnSnowDoesNotKnowNothing sorry the code I write in the satckoverflow is something wrong，i have change it ，please see it again.

Comment: Yeah, the order is always same. I can not say it is coincidence. But please notice, this is not guranteed by java language. And you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124865/java-order-of-execution-after-wait

Comment: @JohnSnowDoesNotKnowNothing so it may be the result of JVM？I used to think It‘s the code I wrote results in the order is always same...I mean it is because there is somewhere i didn’t notice decide the order ....

Comment: It's jvm or operate system, not the code.

Comment: @JohnSnowDoesNotKnowNothing谢谢

Comment: Glad to help  :)

Comment: The javadoc for `o.notify()` does not say that it will choose a waiting thread at random. It says, "The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation." So, it could consistently behave the way you see on your machine, and it could consistently behave in some different way when you run your program on a different machine. The takeaway is, you should write your program in such a way that the order does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The specification of `notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) says:

> If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation.

This implies that you can not expect any particular order while the implementation may use any particular order it wants, including the order in which threads called `wait`.

There is no reason why an implementation should implement shuffling. That would only waste resources. The reason to give implementations that freedom is to allow them to use more efficient algorithms whenever they fit, without having to maintain an order.

So it may happen that a different implementation wakes them up in opposite order due to a different storage structure. It could also change with a certain number of enqueued threads if the implementation switches to a different storage structure above a threshold.

Besides that, your test code is very special. Your main thread waits quiet a long time before calling `notify()`, so it is likely that all threads have already entered the wait state and are stored in whatever data structure the JVM uses. Then, you have only one pending `notify()` at a time, as you let the thread which has been woken up do the next `notify()`. The picture may change dramatically if you allow the operations to overlap.

Then, it may turn out that the underlying data structure is not a pure FIFO. Also, it is quiet common for implementations to allow a thread calling `wait()` to proceed immediately if there is a pending `notify()`, without considering the waiting queue, bypassing all already enqueued threads, because that’s more efficient.

Another point is that if there is more than one pending `notify()`, the threads which have been woken up have to compete for reacquiring the object monitor. It depends on the operating system’s scheduler and the actual system load, which thread will succeed here, so even if the threads were woken up in the order they were enqueued, threads could overtake at this place due to details outside the JVM’s control.

Also, don’t forget that the specification allows *spurious wakeup*. So A JVM not capable of waking up a single thread individually could wake up more than one thread due to a single `notify()` call without violating the specification.

Comment: your answer is so good ，but I dont understand something。as you say ：it is quiet common for implementations to allow a thread calling wait（）to proceed immediately if......does it mean there are several thread waiting in the wait set ，and then a thread calls notify ，as the same time ，another thread X call wait ，the x will be waked up ？is that correct？

Comment: Basically, you got it. Except that *x* will not wake up, as it doesn’t even go to sleep. That’s the point of permitting it, putting a thread to sleep and waking up a thread takes a significant amount of CPU cycles, so allowing an arriving thread to proceed immediately, skipping the sleeping phase altogether, is an optimization that will pay off. On multicore machines, implementations usually even let waiting threads go into a polling loop first for some short time, to allow other threads to fulfill the condition and put them only to sleep when no notification happened during the polling loop.